# Safari not playing audio files stored on google cloud

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, safari, html5-audio

I have a GCP bucket where feedback from people is saved in blob and flac file. On every browser, audio files work but safari doesn't play it.
I have tried changing the order of the audio source tag but no luck.

Here is the reproduce able code. The audio playing on chrome and firefox but not on safari.

```html
 <audio
      autoplay="autoplay"
      controls="controls"
      class="st-virtual-tour-insights__full-audio"
    >
      <source
        src="https://app.askhumans.io/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBcU1tIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ef1f6dd2e6856fdfb82749d8a61f4fa4467390bc/blob"
        type="audio/mpeg"
      />
      <source
        src="https://app.askhumans.io/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBcVFtIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--89ccc36d5163fed5cb31f583921893857ca59b28/blob"
        type="audio/x-flac"
      />
      <source
        src="https://app.askhumans.io/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBcU1tIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ef1f6dd2e6856fdfb82749d8a61f4fa4467390bc/blob"
        type="audio/ogg"
      />
      <source
        src="https://app.askhumans.io/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBcU1tIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ef1f6dd2e6856fdfb82749d8a61f4fa4467390bc/blob"
        type="audio/webm"
      />
    </audio>
```

Comment: Does your safari have a dev console to see errors? If so, open that and check for errors reported.

Comment: No errors. It just doesn't load the source file.

Comment: Have you tried with the correct mimetype `audio/flac` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#flac

Comment: @SananAli, can you also provide the OS version and Safari version as well? It seems that flac is compatible with specific versions of Safari based on this [documentation](https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/flac).

Comment: Kinda late but your ogg, mpeg, and webm urls all point to the same blob in webm format. Your ogg url needs to point to a ogg blob, not a webm blob. Likewise your mpeg url needs to point to a mpeg blob, not a webm blob.

Comment: If you check the urls character for character you will see that are all the same, except for your flac url. I downloaded the "blobs" of the two different urls to learn the file formats: flac and webm.

Comment: It was an urgent fix so we decided to convert to files to mp3 and then use it.